# How do you search multiple strings with the .search() Method?

Tags: javascript, search

Can the .search Method only search for one string? Or is there a way to get one single .search command to search for multiple strings at once? (By the way, I tried the following code:`y.search("c", "b", "a")`, where y is an text box input.)

Comment: You can try with a regex `(a|b|c)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't use multiple arguments, but you can use a regex with the or operator (`|`) like so:

```
y.search(/c|b|a/);
```

This method will work for characters that are more than one character long, as well:

```
y.search(/string1|string2|string3/);
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap multi-character strings in parentheses.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work