# Handle result of multiple .search() arguments

Tags: javascript, search, arguments

As explained in [How do you search multiple strings with the .search() Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251197/how-do-you-search-multiple-strings-with-the-search-method), you can use multiple arguments inside `.search()`.

But how can I know which of the arguments given inside `.search()` returns a positive value?

E.g:

```
var search = string.search("hello|world|not");

if (search.positiveArgument == 1) {
    //"hello" was found
} else if (search.positiveArgument == 2) {
    //"world" was found
etc...
```

*I am aware that `.positiveArgument` isn't valid, it is purely for example purposes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** instead with a regular expression. The matched part will be returned.

For ex: `"yo world".match(/hello|world|not/);` returns `["world"]`

```
var search = str.match(/hello|world|not/);

if (search && search.length === 1) {
    if(search[0] == "hello") {
        // hello was found
    }
    else if(search[0] == "world") {
        // world was found
    }
    else {
        // not was found
    }
}
```