# How to search multiple variables in a string with the .search() method

Tags: javascript

I fount this solution: [How do you search multiple strings with the .search() Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251197/how-do-you-search-multiple-strings-with-the-search-method)

But i need to search using several variables, For example:

```
var String = 'Hire freelance programmers, web developers, designers, writers, data entry & more';
var keyword1 = 'freelance';
var keyword2 = 'web';
String.search(/keyword1|keyword2/);
```

Comment: What if they're both present? Search will only return the first one. Is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to escape the strings before using them in the regular expression (unless you're *certain* they'll never contain any `[`, `|`, etc. chars), then build a `RegExp` object:

```
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

var re = new RegExp( escapeRegExp(keyword1) + "|" + escapeRegExp(keyword2) );
String.search(re);
```

If you have an array of search terms, you could generalize this:

```
var keywords = [ 'one', 'two', 'three[]' ];

var re = new RegExp(
  keywords.map(escapeRegExp).join('|')    // three[] will be escaped to three\[\]
);

String.search(re);
```

Comment: You can't, unless you're certain of the *order* of the keywords. If you're looking for all those keywords in any order, you'd need to search for each string in turn.

Answer (score 3):

You can compose the regex with the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instead of a literal.

```
String.search(new RegExp(keyword1+'|'+keyword2));
```

Answer (score 0):

`search` will only return the index of the first match, it won't search any further. If you wanted to find the indexes for all the keywords you can use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead:

```
var myRe = new RegExp(keyword1 + '|' + keyword2, 'g')
var myArray;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null) {
  var msg = "Found " + myArray[0] + " at position " + myArray.index;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

Found freelance at position 5

Found web at position 28

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vfe2oohj/1/)