# How to find an array of strings in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, string

I'd like to search a string for multiple strings, and return `true` if it finds any of them in there, `false` otherwise, something like this:

```
var s = "thing1 thing2"
s.contains(["thing1","thing44444"]) // true
s.contains("1") // true
s.contains("x") // false
```

Here's what I have so far, but it's getting messier and doesn't really work:

```
String.prototype.contains = function(xv) {
    var t = this
    if(xv.isString()){ // isString/isArray are functions I made elsewhere in my code, they work.
        if(t.indexOf(xv) > -1)
            return true;
    } else if(xv.isArray()) {
        if(xv.contains(t)){
            return true
        }
        for(v in xv){
            if(t.indexOf(xv[v]) > -1){
                return true
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

As of now, it will return `undefined` if it makes it through the `for` loop without finding anything. I had `return false` after the `for` loop, but it would run before the `for` finished.

I feel like there's gotta be an easier way to do this.

I've already tried [How do you search multiple strings with the .search() Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251197/how-do-you-search-multiple-strings-with-the-search-method) but I couldn't send an array to `.search()`.

Frameworks I'm using: angular 1.5.8, jquery 1.11.1

Comment: "I had return false after the for loop, but it would run before the for finished." this isn't possible given the code in your example.

Comment: You may wish to rethink altering the prototype of built in objects, or at least make sure you're polyfilling correctly. See also [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/215552). For instance [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) is already a function in recent versions of JavaScript, and Angular already has [`angular.isString()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isString)...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan from the first answer you quoted: "Changing the behaviour of an object that will only be used by your own code is fine." I do appreciate the references though. Lots of good info here. Thanks brother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) or [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
var s1 = "thing1 thing2";
var s2 = "Hello Kitty";

var r1 = ["thing1","thing44444"].some( x => s1.includes(x));
var r2 = ["Travis","Heeeeeeter"].some( x => s2.includes(x));

console.log(r1, r2); // true, false
```