# Know if a word of a string is in an array Node JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I have a string `var input = "Hello there, my name is Felix"`
and an array `var names = ["John", "Bob", "Felix", "Alicia"]`. How can I know if `input` contains one or multiple words of `names` ?
Thanks.
Edit: I'd like to know what word of `input` is in `names`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find an array of strings in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495372/how-to-find-an-array-of-strings-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Array#filter and String#includes will get all the names included in your input.

```js
const input = "Hello there, my name is Felix"
const names = ["John", "Bob", "Felix", "Alicia"]

const res = names.filter(n=>input.includes(n));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have number of options here, the cleanest in my opinion is the following:

`const namesInString = names.filter( name => input.contains(name) )`
In this approach, filter iterates over the array and stores any given name in the resulting namesInString array, if the name was found in the array.

On an unrelated note, keep in my case sensitivity, so the complete solution should be:
`const namesInString = names.filter( name => input.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase()) )`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with  [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), creating a new [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on every iteration and setting the flag `ignoreCase` if you need it.

```js
const input = "Hello there, my name is Felix";
const names = ["John", "Bob", "Felix", "Alicia", "hello"];

let res = names.filter(name => input.match(RegExp(name, "i")));
console.log("With ignore-case enabled: ", res);

res = names.filter(name => input.match(RegExp(name)));
console.log("Without ignore-case enabled: ", res);
```

However, if you don't mind to get the matches and only need to test is some of the string in the array appears on the input string, you could use a little faster approach using [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const input1 = "Hello there, my name is Felix";
const input2 = "I don't have matches";
const names = ["John", "Bob", "Felix", "Alicia", "hello"];

const res1 = names.some(name => input1.match(RegExp(name, "i")));
console.log("Has coincidences on input1? ", res1);

const res2 = names.some(name => input2.match(RegExp(name, "i")));
console.log("Has coincidences on input2? ", res2);
```