# Can we use or (||) in search()?

Tags: javascript

```
function functiont(){
    var a = document.getElementById("q").value;
    var b = a.toLowerCase();
    var x = b.search("news"||"headline"||"headlines");//is this possible?
    if(x != -1){
        $("p").text("here are the results");
    } else{
        $("p").text("sorry");
    }
```

Is the following thing possible or I have to create more variables and search for all the keywords?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you search multiple strings with the .search() Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251197/how-do-you-search-multiple-strings-with-the-search-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in the search method:

```
b.search(/news|headline|headlines/);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Comment: To add to this answer, you don't need the plural of headline to be listed, as the match will occur no matter is there is an 's' or not with this regex.

Comment: @Benedikt Thanks a lot

Comment: @Kuu Aku Thanks a lot